# Why do I get s=-1807786450?

Tags: c

Each new term in the Fibonacci sequence is generated by adding the previous two terms. By starting with 1 and 2, the first 10 terms will be:

1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, ...

By considering the terms in the Fibonacci sequence whose values do not exceed four million, find the sum of the even-valued terms.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main (void)
{
    int a=0,b=1,c,s=0;
    int i=1,f=0;
    
    while(i<100000)
    {
        c=a+b;
        if(c%2==0)  
        {
            //printf("c=%ld \n",c);
            s+=c; 
            //f++;
        }
        
        a=b;
        b=c;
        i++;
    }   
    printf("s=%d ",s);
    //  printf("f=%ld",f);
}
```

Comment: Also, the 100000th Fibonacci number is over 4 million.

Comment: I tried double unsigned long it didn't work

Comment: @MooingDuck `int` is usually 32 bits, so it can hold numbers over 2 billion.

Comment: You don't need such large numbers. You should stop when `c > 4000000`

Comment: Here is a list of limits of c type: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/limits_h.htm

Comment: @Barmar: I was off by a factor of 1000, my mistake

Comment: `while (i < 1000000)` should be `while (c <= 4000000)`

Answer (score 1):

Because you didn't initialize a and b, so they contain garbage. If you make a =0 and b = 0, for example, your s value will become 0.

Comment: If you start with both of them 0, it will just produce an infinite sequence of 0.

Comment: Uninitialized values and undefined behaviour strikes again!

Comment: @Barmar I just gave an example. This does not negate the fact that you always need to keep track of the variables :)

Comment: Of course. But it's not enough to just initialize the variables, you have to initialize them to the correct values for the algorithm.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. While he missed initializing the variables in the question, a=0,b=1 results in the exact error he gets.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop condition is bad, for one thing - you're looping while `i` is less than `100000`.  The problem with that is that the maximum Fibonacci term you can represent in a signed `int` is `F(46)`, or `1836311903`<sup>1</sup> - once you compute `F(47)` the value in `c` overflows and anything computed from that is garbage.

Since the requirement is to sum even Fibonacci values up to four million, your condition needs to be

```
while ( c <= 4000000 )
{
  ...
}
```

---

1. Assuming a 32-bit `int`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the code which gives it the strange error.

The most problematic error is that the `int` number is too small to contain all sums. The constant `INT_MAX` reports the maximum value for 32-bit machines as `2,147,483,647`. In contrast, the 100,000th fibbonacci number computed is... large...

[image: Wolfram result for "100000th fibbonacci"]

[(Wolfram result for 100,000th fibbonacci number)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=100000th%20fibbonacci)

Which brings to the second issue, as [John Bode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67186396/12664675) mentioned: You're not summing up all fibbonacci numbers less than 4 million; you're summing up the first 100,000 fibbonacci numbers.

Replace the condition in your `while` loop to this:

```
while (c <= 4000000)
{
    // ...
}
```

If you still get a negative/overwrapped number, consider replacing your `int`s with `long`s instead.